# How to properly pass a $string with spaces into grep

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

i tried to make bash script that can find "keyword" inside *.desktop file. my approach is to set some keyword as array, then pass it to grep, it work flawlessly until the keyword has at least two word separated by space.

what it should be

```
cat /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | grep -i "Mail Reader"
```

what i have tried

```
search=$(printf 'Name=%s' "${appsx[$index]}")
echo \""$search\"" #debug
cat /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | grep -i $search
```

```
search=$(printf 'Name=%s' "${appsx[$index]}")
echo \""$search\"" #debug
cat /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | grep -i \""$search\""
```

```
search=$(printf '"Name=%s"' "${appsx[$index]}")
echo $search #debug
cat /usr/share/applications/*.desktop | grep -i $search
```

any suggestions is highly appreciated

Comment: You almost always should put double-quotes around variable references: `grep -i "$search"`. Also, `printf` looks like overkill here; just use `search="Name=${appsx[$index]}"`. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend. Oh, and one more thing: `cat | grep` is an unnecessary use of `cat`, just use `grep -i "$search" /usr/share/applications/*.desktop`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for that. I didn't see the op had quotes inside the command substitution. The fact that they had spaces in the result was pretty obvious. I have rectified it in my answer..

Comment: the reason i use `$(printf 'Name=%s' "${appsx[$index]}")` because `readarray apps < ${file2}` give me extra `\n` is there are some way to overcome this?

Comment: @CatzyRais By default, `readarray` includes the line terminator (newline aka `\n`) in the created array entries. To avoid this, use `readarray -t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply assign `Mail Reader` to the variable search like below

```
search=Mail Reader
```

`bash` would complain that `Reader` command is not found as it takes anything after that first blank character to be a subsequent command. What you need is

```
search="Mail Reader" # 'Mail Reader' would also do.
```

In the case of your command substitution, things are not different, you need double quote wrappers though, as the substitution itself would not happen inside the single
quotes

```
search="$(command)"
```

In your case, you did an overkill using a command substitution though. It could be well simplified to:

```
search="Name=${appsx[$index]}"
# Then do the grep.
# Note that cat-grep combo could be simplified to
# -h suppresses printing filenames to get same result as cat .. | grep
grep -ih "$search" /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

Comment: `cat files | grep ...` is different from `grep ... files`: The second one lists the filenames too. Adding `-h` suppresses the filenames. I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, double quote your variables should be enough

```
grep -i "$search"
```

but if that string variable starts with `-` (hyphen), you have to make a distinction, otherwise grep will recognize your variable as a command option

```
grep -i -- "$search"
```